# Change breakpoint accordion vs. tabs product data

Tags: tabs, rwd, accordion

I'm struggling with my product tabs. I've that many tabs, that the tabs are wrapped to a new line. For this reason, I would like the breakpoint to change to an accordion from `screen__m` to `screen__l`.

I've tried many, many things already, I think it has to do with calling `.lib-data-tabs()` and `.lib-data-accordion()` in the correct media selector. But whatever I do, the default Magento breakpoint seems to 'win'.

The strange thing is when I open my site on an iPad it defaults to 'tabs view' in portrait mode. When I do so on Safari, and scale to viewport width `< 768px` and then back to iPad view, it seems to stay in accordion mode. Leading me to believe that 'both' tabs and accordion `styles_l` and `styles_m` are valid, but it simply is the `styles_l` version that is loaded last, and thus ending up with tabs instead of accordion.

It would seem so easy to fix the breakpoint to **1024** instead of **768**, but I'm pulling my hairs out.

Can anyone help?

thx,
Rene

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the following less code, sure it could be made more efficient though:

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__s) {
    .product.data.items {
        .lib-data-accordion();
    }
}
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .product.data.items {
        .lib-data-accordion();
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: @screen__m) {
    .product.data.items {
        .lib-data-accordion();
    }
}
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .product.data.items {
        .lib-data-tabs();
    }
}
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__l) {
    .product.data.items {
        .lib-data-tabs();
    }
}
```